# VS2008 Command Prompt + Cygwin

Tags: command-line, cygwin

I use the VS2008 command prompt for builds, TFS access etc. and the cygwin prompt for grep, vi and unix-like tools. Is there any way I can 'import' the vcvars32.bat functionality into the cygwin environment so I can call "tfs checkout" from cygwin itself?

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366928/invoking-cl-exe-msvc-compiler-in-cygwin-shell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/research/vr/Dive/Local/compile.html) you need to:

"Depending on your preference, you can either add the variables required for compilation direct to your environment, or use the vcvars32.bat script to set them for you. Note you have to compile from a cygwin bash shell, to use vcvars32, first run a DOS shell, then run vcvars32.bat, then run cygwin.bat from the directory where you installed cygwin. You can speed this up by adding the directory containgin vcvars32 (somewhere under \Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\bin) and the directory containing cygwin.bat to your path."

Answer (score 10):

Here is my sample Cygwin.bat file that configures Visual studio and starts mintty

```
@echo off
@REM Select the latest VS Tools
IF  EXIST %VS100COMNTOOLS% (
    CALL "%VS100COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
    GOTO :start_term
)

IF  EXIST %VS90COMNTOOLS% (
    CALL "%VS90COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
    GOTO :start_term
)

IF  EXIST %VS80COMNTOOLS% (
    CALL "%VS80COMNTOOLS%\vsvars32.bat"
    GOTO :start_term
)

:start_term

C:
chdir C:\cygwin\bin
START mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

Comment: call "%VS90COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat" is more generic (and shorter).

Comment: I like it! Adding to the answer.

Comment: This works for msys too, assuming you switch out the launch command appropriately.  GG

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The minty shell (using zsh) that opens doesn't have the environment settings. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

witkamp's answer works for vs2005 -- for vs2008, use

CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"