# z3 ocaml binding not working (windows 7)

Tags: binding, windows-7, ocaml, z3

I am not getting the z3 ocaml binding working on windows 7.
Here is the process I followed.

1. Installed Objective Caml version 3.11.0 (Microsoft toolchain)
2. Installed camlidl-1.05 (built it using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 + cygwin)
3. Installed z3-3.0
4. Built z3 ocaml binding by running "build.cmd".The build was successful.
5. Copied the files generated by "build.cmd" from z3/ocaml to ObjectiveCaml/lib
6. Launched ocaml interactive and loaded "z3.cma"

   ```
   # #load "z3.cma";;
   Characters -1--1:
     #load "z3.cma";;

   Error: The external function `get_theory_callbacks' is not available

   # Z3.mk_context;;
   Characters -1--1:
     Z3.mk_context;;

   Error: The external function `camlidl_z3_Z3_mk_context' is not available
   ```

Can someone please give me some hints?

EDIT 1:
**Building the example in "Z3-3.0\examples\ocaml":**

Excerpt from *build.cmd*

```
set XCFLAGS=/nologo /MT /DWIN32
ocamlopt -ccopt "%XCFLAGS%" -o test_mlapi.exe -I ..\..\ocaml ole32.lib %OCAMLLIB%\libcamlidl.lib z3.cmxa test_mlapi.ml
```

I got the following error on executing *build.cmd* in the *Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt*

```
** Fatal error: Cannot find file "/nologo"
File "caml_startup", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error during linking
```

On removing the `-ccopt "%XCFLAGS%"`, it works fine. The generated *exe* also executes as expected. ( Note that I have flexdll in PATH ). Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you managed to build the example (examples\ocaml) using the ocaml bindings? I built the example using the Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: @Leonardo de Moura: Thanks for pointing to the examples directory. On building the example, I got the following error.
** Fatal error: Cannot find file "/nologo"
File "caml_startup", line 1, characters 0-1:
Error: Error during linking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml version 3.11 and later call the linker through flexdll, which does not need or know about the "/nologo /MT /DWIN32" flags.  The ocaml\build.cmd script tests the ocaml version and sets XCFLAGS appropriately.  I guess that examples\ocaml\build.cmd should be changed to do the same.

Using Z3 from the toplevel works for me if I create a custom toplevel by executing 'ocamlmktop -o ocamlz3 z3.cma' from Z3 ocaml bindings directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to modify the command slightly to make it work with my setup. `ocamlmktop -o ocamlz3 z3.cma %OCAMLLIB%\libcamlidl.lib ole32.lib`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me (Windows 7):

1. Download and install Ocaml 3.08+
   ​
2. Download and install Visual Studio C++
   ​
3. Download and extract CamlIDL
   ​
4. Download and install cygwin, while installing choose the *make* package as well as your favorite linux editor package in a "Select package" window.
   ​
5. Open cygwin 
   ​
6. In cygwin go to CamlIDL root directory
   ​
7. Rename `config/Makefile.win32` to `config/Makefile`
   ​
8. Open `config/Makefile` with an editor
   ​
9. Edit `BINLIB` and `OCAMLLIB` variables
   ​​
10. Save and exit the `Makefile`
    ​
11. Setup c compiler for cygwin: [Invoking cl.exe (MSVC compiler) in Cygwin shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366928/invoking-cl-exe-msvc-compiler-in-cygwin-shell/3272301#3272301)
    ​
12. Run `make all` from CamlIDL root directory
    ​
13. Run `make install`
    ​
14. Exit cygwin
    ​
15. Download and install Z3
    ​
16. Download and install FlexDLL: http://alain.frisch.fr/flexdll.html
    ​
17. Click Start, point to My Computer, right click, point to Properties, point to System Protection, choose Advanced Tab, point to Environment values...
    ​
18. Add `C:\Program Files\flexdll\` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-<version-number>\bin\` to the Path variable
    ​
19. Click Start, point to All Programs, point to Microsoft Visual Studio, point to Visual Studio Tools, and then click Visual Studio Command Prompt.
    ​
20. In Visual Studio Command Prompt go to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-<version-number>\ocaml`
    ​​
21. Open `build.cmd` with an editor
    ​
22. Remove `%CD%` variable from the last two commands
    ​
23. Save and close `build.cmd`
    ​
24. Run `build.cmd`
    ​
25. Copy z3* and libz3.lib files generated by build.cmd from `z3/ocaml` to `%OCAMLLIB%`
    ​
26. Run `ocamlmktop -o ocamlz3 z3.cma %OCAMLLIB%\libcamlidl.lib ole32.lib`
    ​
27. Run `ocamlz3.exe`
    ​
28. Type `#use "../examples/ocaml/test_mlapi.ml";;`
    ​
29. Try `simple_example();;​`
30. The last step should produce a valid output from Z3.

​
For Debian/Ubuntu:

1. Install Ocaml 3.09+
   ​ 1. `sudo apt-get install camlidl​`
2. `git clone git://github.com/polazarus/z3-installer.git` *(from Mickaël Delahaye)*
3. `cd z3-installer`
4. `make` *# download Z3 AND build the Ocaml library (native and byte)*
5. `sudo make install` *# install Z3 binary, DLL and the Ocaml library*
6. `sudo cp z3/lib/libz3.so /usr/lib/`
7. `cd z3/ocaml`
8. `ocamlmktop -o ocamlz3 z3.cma`
9. .`/ocamlz3`
10. Try the following snippet:

> `let simple_example() =` 
>    `begin`
>     `Printf.printf "\nsimple_example\n";`
>     `let ctx = Z3.mk_context_x (Array.append [|("MODEL", "true")|] [||]) in`
>     `Printf.printf "CONTEXT:\n%sEND OF CONTEXT\n" (Z3.context_to_string ctx);`
>     `Z3.del_context ctx;`
>    `end;;`
>   `simple_example();;​`