# install qt5.11 headles using the script option

Tags: javascript, qt, installation

My goal is to install Qt 5.11.1 on my headless ubuntu server 18.04.1 running jenkins2.

I am currently testing my current script on a virtual box running ubuntu desktop 18.04.
note that i have not trouble installing or running qt if install using the gui installer manually

When trying to install qt using the installer gui free approach i get the following problem running using the terminal.

```
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.11.1.run --script qt-installer-noninteractive.qs --platform minimal --verbose
or
./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run --script qt-installer-noninteractive.qs --platform minimal --verbose

...
...
[9732] Warning: Other components depend on component qt.tools which has child components. This will not work properly.
[9745] Warning: Component qt.qt5.5111 depends on other components while having child components. This will not work properly.
```

When The process finish a Qt folder is created containg qtcreator but no qt library is included.

qt-installer-noninteractive.qs

```
function Controller() {
    installer.autoRejectMessageBoxes();
    installer.installationFinished.connect(function() {
        gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
    })
}

Controller.prototype.WelcomePageCallback = function() {
    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
}

Controller.prototype.CredentialsPageCallback = function() {
    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
}

Controller.prototype.IntroductionPageCallback = function() {
    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
}

Controller.prototype.TargetDirectoryPageCallback = function()
{
    gui.currentPageWidget().TargetDirectoryLineEdit.setText(installer.value("HomeDir") + "/Qt");
    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
}

Controller.prototype.ComponentSelectionPageCallback = function() {
    var widget = gui.currentPageWidget();

    widget.deselectAll();

// pretty sure the line below is the problem, but cant find a list over the proper paths to use for linux.

    widget.selectComponent("qt.5111.gcc_64");  
    //widget.selectComponent("qt.55.qtquickcontrols");

    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.tools.qtcreator");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.55.qt3d");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.55.qtcanvas3d");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.55.qtlocation");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.55.qtquick1");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.55.qtscript");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.55.qtwebengine");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.extras");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.tools.doc");
    // widget.deselectComponent("qt.tools.examples");

    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
}

Controller.prototype.LicenseAgreementPageCallback = function() {
    gui.currentPageWidget().AcceptLicenseRadioButton.setChecked(true);
    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,10000);
}

Controller.prototype.StartMenuDirectoryPageCallback = function() {
    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
}

Controller.prototype.ReadyForInstallationPageCallback = function()
{
    gui.clickButton(buttons.NextButton,3000);
}

Controller.prototype.FinishedPageCallback = function() {
var checkBoxForm = gui.currentPageWidget().LaunchQtCreatorCheckBoxForm
if (checkBoxForm && checkBoxForm.launchQtCreatorCheckBox) {
    checkBoxForm.launchQtCreatorCheckBox.checked = false;
}
    gui.clickButton(buttons.FinishButton);
}
```

I have used the following resources but without any luck.

[stack overflow: silent Qt install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105269/silent-install-qt-run-installer-on-ubuntu-server)

[Qt installer no interactive installer documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html)

[stack overflow, Silent install for Windows listing a set of commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735724/silent-install-qt55-enterprise-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

to get the binaries component for qt 5.11.1 this is the correct path to add

```
widget.selectComponent("qt.qt5.5111.gcc_64");
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the correct path for *MSVC* binaries is `widget.selectComponent("qt.qt5.5111.win64_msvc2015_64");`.

Answer (score 2):

The script never worked for me (or I was just too dumb to use it), but I wrote a more or less simple python script that basically does the same as the official Qt installer does. You can find it [here](https://git.kaidan.im/lnj/qli-installer).

This is how to install the dependencies and run it:

```
sudo apt install python3-requests p7zip-full wget

wget https://git.kaidan.im/lnj/qli-installer/raw/master/qli-installer.py
chmod +x qli-installer.py

./qli-installer.py 5.11.3 linux desktop
```

Then the Qt installation can be found at `./5.11.3/gcc_64/` in this case. With other systems/targets (i.e. `linux android android_armv7`) this will differ of course.

Comment: Unfortunately your script does not does not change Qt install path / rpath.
See "qmake  --version" that shows /home/qt/work/install/lib and not the path the script installed Qt.
One might be able to use Qt, but in quite some cases not.

Comment: aqtinstall (based on the script) fixes the problem:
https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall

Answer (score 0):

You could just forward X through ssh to your local machine..

See https://www.businessnewsdaily.com/11035-how-to-use-x11-forwarding.html

E.g. ssh -X root@headless_server_ip

Run your ./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.1.1-online.run and the installer GUI will pop up on your ssh client (that has an X server). Follow the install steps and .. voila..