# Erroneous link error running cl.exe/MSPDB110.DLL on cygwin bash via ssh

Tags: windows, bash, visual-studio-2012, cygwin, cl.exe

On Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012. Attempting to build via cygwin bash just using cl.exe and cygwin/gnu make. I've got my bash environment vars set correctly with clues from;

[Invoking cl.exe (MSVC compiler) in Cygwin shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366928/invoking-cl-exe-msvc-compiler-in-cygwin-shell) and
[VS2008 Command Prompt + Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029/vs2008-command-prompt-cygwin/168447#168447)

(I simply diff the environment vars before and after running vcvarsX.bat, tweak that list a little and set it in my bash session. It works)

I have a hello world test.c and makefile which builds fine in the console cygwin bash, but fails in an ssh *if* the /debug switch is set. Without the /debug it builds.

Here's a copy of my ssh session without and with the /debug switch;

http://pastebin.com/zY39i2c6

I believe the link error (near the bottom) to be erroneous since it works fine in the console bash. It's just the ssh bash that gives the link error *only if* the /debug switch is set.

I suspect that the MSPDB110.DLL is a "windows" module (as opposed to a true console program) and fails to execute in the ssh process, as I've seen happen when trying to run other non-console programs in a cygwin ssh. But this is just my guess. In the pastebin you'll also see that I show where the cl.exe and mspdb110 are coming from (which cl.exe near the bottom).

I find many posts/threads discussing doing this in cygwin bash sessions, but don't find anyone attempting to do it via ssh.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your remote box using Cygwin 1.7? See `A Note on Compiling through Cygwin SSHd` in http://code.google.com/p/qt-msvc-installer/.

I could also suggest that you try finding the DLL in the MSVS directory and add the directory where it's placed to PATH as `PATH=/cygwin/c/path/to/dir:$PATH`.

Comment: Cygwin 1.7 check. Correct PATH check. I changed my sshd to 'UsePrivilegeSeparation no' and my own user id, and now it works. Thanks konsolebox!