# Running MSVC 'cl.exe' from Git Bash (MINGW64)

Tags: windows, bash, visual-c++

I'm trying to find a way to invoke the Visual Studio C++ compiler (MSVC) from within my Git Bash terminal on Windows.
The Developer Command Prompt for VS2017 works fine, it's just annoying to switch between windows just to compile my application.

I tried adding `cl.exe` to my Path and was unsuccessful. Google keeps pointing me toward using GCC, which I'm not interested in doing. I was also able to find these two questions, both about Cygwin, [one about invoking cl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366928/invoking-cl-exe-msvc-compiler-in-cygwin-shell) and another about [importing vcvars32.bat funcationality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029/vs2008-command-prompt-cygwin/168447#168447) (They're linked to each other). The issue is that 1) these are for Cygwin, not MINGW64, and 2) point me to `vcvars32.bat/VsDevCmd.bat`. That script seems to mainly be for setting up the development environment (It also passes all smoke tests invoked by `VsDevCmd.bat` if that matters.).

So my question(s) is/are:
Is this possible?
How do I resolve `bash: cl: command not found` and allow calling `cl.exe` from Git Bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple workaround: launch your Git Bash terminal from inside a Developer Command Prompt terminal so that it inherits the environment.

Longer (but more flexible): Convert vcvars32.bat to a bash script and source it.

Answer (score 5):

```
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.9.8
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\>f:\git\usr\bin\bash.exe        

$ cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]
```